# Using TensorFlow in ROS2

Tags: c++, cmake, ros-humble

I'm trying to add gesture recognition capabilities in my ros2 humble C++ package, and I started out with trying to use the TensorFlow C++ API. However, I am unable to install TensorFlow for my ROS2 package.

I have tried this link: https://github.com/ika-rwth-aachen/tensorflow_cpp/tree/fix/cmake

However, following the instructions gives me the following error when trying to build:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
   By not providing "FindTensorFlow.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
   "TensorFlow", but CMake did not find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "TensorFlow" with
   any of the following names:

     TensorFlowConfig.cmake
     tensorflow-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "TensorFlow" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "TensorFlow_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
   "TensorFlow" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
   been installed.
```

Any other links that would be helpful? Or even other approaches to gesture recognition?

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CMake produces this error when it is trying to find a required resource (in this case, TensorFlow) but can't.

- Do you have TensorFlow installed? If not, [follow the installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install).
- Do you have TensorFlow on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? This environment variable is used by CMake to find available libraries, so if it isn't, you'll want to [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux).

Comment: Ok. But would installing through pip, as is written in the TensorFlow instructions work for me?

Comment: You are using C/C++, so you should follow the C/C++ instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c